# Golang - slice of socket linked to an id for notification

Tags: list, sockets, go, tcp

I want to make a slice of struct which contains an id and a socket to send notifications from my server. Each socket have to be initialized and I understand how a socket works because I already worked with it (in C, clustering for school project with select()).

However I don't understand how can I separate each new connection into a element of my slice (When I read the example from [systembash](https://systembash.com/a-simple-go-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)).. It's hard to say what I don't understand, message me if you don't understand !

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Make a struct that includes both the `conn` and `id`:

```
type ConnDetails struct {
   connection net.Conn
   id         int
}
```

Use this to initialize your slice:

```
var connections []ConnDetails
```

Then, you can add all connections into this slice.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank for your answer ! :) Yes for half of my question ;) I saw this part and I already code this part ;) However, how to init each socket? I mean, unlike the link I gave, like a function as listener to the socket. I also don't see how to save a new socket into an elem "ConnDetails".

Comment: If you refer the documentation, (https://godoc.org/net ), you'll know how to get the connection using net.Listener.Accept() method. Then you initialize a variable : connDetail := ConnDetails{connection: <the result from Accept()>, id:<whatever your id generation logic is>}; Then, insert this into the slice using append() method.